# Plotting vectors and curves on a 3D surface

Tags: graphics3d

I am having trouble plotting curves on surfaces.  I have searched for similar examples and I have tried both Plot3D and ParametricPlot3D commands and experimented with Epilog and MeshFunctions (et.c) without success.

Goal: to plot a curve and a line segment (or, it could be a vector) on a surface.  The curve follows the surface.

The Sin[x] function is a reasonable surface although my surface I am using is constructed via a ParametricPlot3D command from an Interpolation function generated from data numerically computed by an external program.
But, if I know how to do this with Sin[x] via ParametricPlot3D I can do it with my Interpolation function.

Here is a Sin[x] function plotted using:

[image]

Notice that a surface and a curve is plotted, the curve being the $2\sin{x}$ value along $y=2$.  I have not yet figured out how to highlight the curve with different color or thickness but that is not may main question.    I would like to have this $2\sin{x}$ curve run from points $(2.3,2)\rightarrow (4.0,2)$ only and of course highlighted by a different color.  Another line (on the surface) would extend from points $(2.3,2)$ to $(4.0,4)$.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem was that your line did not depend upon $y$.  `ParametricPlot3D` functions use both variables and produces fundamentally two-dimensional surfaces when you have two variables.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{
  {x, y, 2 Sin[x]},
  {x, 2 + y/50, 2 Sin[x]}
  },
 {x, 0, 3 π}, {y, 0, 6},
 PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[0.5], Pink}, {Black}}]
```

Best is to make the plot of the line a function of just one variable:

```
a = ParametricPlot3D[
   {x, y, 2 Sin[x]},
   {x, 0, 3 π}, {y, 0, 6},
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5], Pink}];
b = ParametricPlot3D[{x, 2, 2 Sin[x]},
   {x, 0, 2 π},
   PlotStyle -> Blue];
Show[a, b]
```

[image]

Comment: I attempted to mark as answer but it is not working for some reason.  But, this worked and I am kicking myself (not too easy to do though) because I did not realize the solution you posted -- I should have.

Comment: I now see that the answer mark is posted -- had to refresh the page though.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the options `Mesh` and `MeshFunctions` with a single `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
a = 2; b = 2 Pi;
ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, 2 Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 3 Pi}, {v, 0, 6}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &, ConditionalExpression[#2 - 2, a <= # <= b] &},
  Mesh -> { 15, Range[0, 6, .5], {{0, Directive[Thick, Red]}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]